# "Debug assertion failed" error

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

there is debug assertion failed error. Can someone get to the probem.

> Debug Assertion Failed !
>
> Program:..
>   File:fclose.c
>   Line:47
>
> Expression:(stream!=Null)

I am debugging the code in visual studio.

Here is the Part of the code:

```
int __cdecl fclose (
        FILE *stream
        )
{
        int result = EOF;

        _VALIDATE_RETURN((stream != NULL), EINVAL, EOF);

        /* If stream is a string, simply clear flag and return EOF */
        if (stream->_flag & _IOSTRG)
                stream->_flag = 0;  /* IS THIS REALLY NEEDED ??? */

        /* Stream is a real file. */
        else {
                _lock_str(stream);
                __try {
                        result = _fclose_nolock(stream);
                }
                __finally {
                        _unlock_str(stream);
                }
        }

        return(result);
}
```

Comment: Run in the debugger, when the assertion happens the program will stop, and you can go up the call stack to your code. There you can see that you're passing a `NULL` pointer to `fclose` which is what the assertion is about. Check your code to see why you call `fclose` with a `NULL` pointer, maybe you forgot to check the return from `fopen`?

Answer (score 1):

Check the callers of `fclose()`. Don't feed a NULL `FILE*` to it.